# Try Catch Finally doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: visual-studio, try-catch, return-value, compiler-warnings, try-catch-finally

I was working doing a lot of refactoring in a legacy code, and I found this:

```
Public Function GetDocumentTypes() As DataSet
        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
        Try
            ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Conn, "USP_DocumentTypes_Get")
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler.Publish(ex, ExceptionDestinationEmail, TSecurity.GetUserID)
        Finally
            If ds IsNot Nothing Then
                ds.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
        Return ds
    End Function
```

And I started doing a research about how the try catch finally flow works, and I realize that in this case always the ds will be nothing because of the finally statement, then I changed the code to:

```
Public Function GetDocumentTypes() As DataSet
        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
        Try
            ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Conn, "USP_DocumentTypes_Get")
            Return ds
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler.Publish(ex, ExceptionDestinationEmail, TSecurity.GetUserID)
        Finally
            If ds IsNot Nothing Then
                ds.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
```

Then started receiving a compiler warning:
[image: Function doesn't return a value on all code paths.]

At the end I solved the issue writing the code like this:

```
Public Function GetDocumentTypes() As DataSet
        Dim ds As DataSet = Nothing
        Try
            ds = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Conn, "USP_DocumentTypes_Get")
            Return ds
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorHandler.Publish(ex, ExceptionDestinationEmail, TSecurity.GetUserID)
            Return ds
        Finally
            If ds IsNot Nothing Then
                ds.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try
    End Function
```

is that the best way to do it??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that seems like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, just when you call that function do something like this so you know your dataset has a value and did not went in the catch statement:

```
if Not GetDocumentTypes is nothing then
'your code here
end if
```